# Perform after_success actions conditionally?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm working on a project that deploys to a provider not currently supported by Travis, so I've written my deployment step in an `after_success` block. However, I'd like to configure Travis to only deploy on new tags. I know this is possible when using the `deploy:` block, by adding

```yaml
deploy:
  # ...
  on:
    tags: true
```

to the `deploy:` block.

Is the same possible in `after_success`? If not, is there another way to only do certain actions in `after_success` if I'm on a new tag?

If Travis doesn't support this, I can just write a shell script to run after all successes, check if on a new tag, and then conditionally do the deployment, but I'd much prefer to be able to have Travis do it automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yep! I need the exact same thing and worked around it by doing:

```
after_success:
  if ([ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ] || [ ! -z "$TRAVIS_TAG" ]) && 
      [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == "false" ]; then
    echo "This will deploy!"
  else
    echo "This will not deploy!"
  fi
```

I hope they introduce the on: tags: functionality for the after_success event, it'll make things easier and keep the build script cleaner.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much. I didn't know you could embed a bash script in the `.travis.yml` - I was going to write a separate script file and have Travis run it.

Comment: You're welcome! Travis is awesome, it's super flexible!

Comment: Definitely, it's a great service! Thanks again for your help.